# Why is my GridView is in front of the rest of my UI

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin, gridview

My gridview is on top of both my toolbar and floating action button, anyone know how to fix that? Also, i want to have a bit of space at the top and the bottom of the gridview, but for that space to not stay when i scroll up and down, however i think i can achieve that by setting clipToPadding to false, which fixes it partially, but there is still a small gap at the top and bottom. Thanks in advance!

My toolbar xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity_Main.xml (contains my gridview):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/book_grid"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My custom gridview item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/book_cover_background">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/book_cover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/book_grid_cover"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_missing" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/book_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/book_cover"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/book_grid_title"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/book_author"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/book_title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/book_grid_title"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you post an image of what you achieved and what you want?

Comment: it looks like https://imgur.com/a/e5G8ItQ atm, and i want it to look the same, only behind the toolbar and fab

Comment: Try with writing the GridView as first element of your layout

Comment: Doesnt help  unfortunately